# MATLAB: Forcing a function to return a solution if it's taking too long

Tags: matlab

I am trying to feed 10,000 empirical data sets to a function, one after the other. The data sets are similar each time, but there are some small differences.

Usually the routine works fine, but occasionally (due to the small differences) the function will be given a data set that it will not be able to resolve, or will not be able to resolve within several hours.

I don't care that much if that data set doesn't get used. Is there some way to edit the function so it says "if this data set is too taking too long, just return some arbitrary values to the script so that we can move on"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'now' function to get a current datenum as you enter the function.
At some point in the function you could use it again and check the difference to see if the delta is longer than your threshold for waiting (in seconds).

```
starttime = now;
% processing block
if (now - starttime) > 3600
    return (junk answer)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the function, call `t_start = tic();` when it starts.

You can check the then check number of seconds elapsed with `t_elapsed = toc(t_start);`

If your function has lots of loops, you can check `toc(t_start)` each loop and return some error condition if the elapsed time gets too big.